# Is there a way to convert a variable to a constant in java?

Tags: java, spring, variables, annotations, constants

I want to set the value for a spring annotation at the runtime by reading the property file. I can read the value form the property file and assign to a variable, but annotations only accepts "constants", **is it possible to change this variable to constant ** and use it as the value for the annotation ?

> So as I already explain "Is it possible to convert a variable to a constant in java"?

Comment: No.  Annotations happen at compile time.  You probably need to consider another way to solve your problem.

Comment: Your question does not make sense.  You are not reading a variable from a property file, you are reading a property value.  You can then use the `@Value` annotation to assign the property value to a variable in your class.

Answer (score 1):

You can't *convert* a variable to a constant, but, depending on the scope, you can create a new `final` variable and initialise it with the non-const variable. This worked for me both inside a method and in the class itself

```
int test = 10;
final int test2 = test;
```